# GridView 'CheckedChanged' event only firing once

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView, which features a a checkbox on each row (in a template field), where it calls a method upon checked changed (well, when they click submit - no auto post back)

My problem is, the checked change refuses to fire more than once - if I just change the check state of one checkbox in the grid, it works fine. More than one and it only fires the event once.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Bit of code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludedLocal" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Included") %>' 
                        Enabled="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIncludedLocal_CheckedChanged" />
```

And in the event, I put a breakpoint right at the top to see how many times it fires

Comment: Have you taken this outside gridview or as Templatefield inside gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted - I was stupidly rebinding the GridView after the event, which caused the other checks to reset. Doh.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Remove the question then if you got the answer as there is nothing in it to do